# How to use sed to replace a string within a larger string

Tags: sed

I'm sure this has been written somewhere before... I'm trying to use sed to replace a string with the following format which is within a larger string:

```
EFF=<some text>;
```

The string always starts with 'EFF=' and ends with a ';'

I've tried the following but somehow it deletes far more than its supposed to (instead of just deleting this particular section, it deletes up until the final ';' in the larger string), so I'm not sure whether I can be more specific in my command:

```
sed -i 's/EFF=.*;//g'
```

eg of larger string:

```
<some text>;EFF=<some text>;<some text>;<some text>;
```

The "some text" is not identical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is greedy, it matches the longest possible string. You need to exclude `;` from the match.

```
sed -i 's/EFF=[^;]*;//g' filename
```

Comment: That did the trick... may I ask what [^;] means in this context?

Comment: Please go to regular-expressions.info to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: `[^;]` means every character that is `not ;`